# Google Analytics BigQuery Export: Getting Different Number for Revenue

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query for the transaction totals with the intention to match the interface.  Google Analytics has a demo account that I am using for my testing.  The data for this account can also be accessed in BigQuery.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT date,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue/1000000) AS revenue,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160801'
GROUP BY date
```

I get this:

```
Row  date       revenue
1    20160801   6116.0599999999995
```

This differs from the results I get out of the interface which is $6,098.47.  Rounding error aside, I expect the number to match.  This is similar behavior to what I see in data for my own Google Analytics tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a deprecated field. try `totals.totalTransactionRevenue` instead:

```sql
SELECT 
  date,
  SUM(totals.totaltransactionRevenue/1000000) AS revenue,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160801'
GROUP BY date
```